# How to exclude specific folder while creating angular build

Tags: build, angular6, ng-build

I have below folder structure of my angular application

```
web\src\app\main
```

in main folder I have folder for different modules like

```
web\src\app\main\userinfo

web\src\app\main\packages
```

Location of  `tsconfig.app.json` is `scr/tsconfig.app.json`

I want to exclude `userinfo` and `packages` folder completely form the build

I added below code in `tsconfig.app.json` to exclude `userInfo`

```
    "exclude": [
         "src/test.ts",
          "**/*.spec.ts",
         "./src/app/main/userinfo/"
    ]
```

But it's not working
The build size is same,

If this module is not included then build size should get reduce